# SubQuery com Linq

Tags: c#, query, linq

Preciso fazer uma consulta com Linq de um objeto chamado Cliente. Esse objeto tem um relacionamento com outro objeto, que se trata de uma List  de telefones. Para cada um dos telefones, existe um tipo: `'Casa', 'Comercial', 'Recado'`, etc.

Quero trazer tudo na mesma consulta. Como faço isso com Linq?

Segue o exemplo do que já está feito:

```
var pf = (from p in contexto.PFPJ
                      join pais in contexto.Pais on p.IDPais equals pais.ID
                      join profissao in contexto.Profissao on p.IDProfissao equals profissao.ID
                      join cargos in contexto.Cargo on p.IDCargo equals cargos.ID
                      join nacionalidade in contexto.Nacionalidade on p.IDNacionalidade equals nacionalidade.ID
                      join estadoCivil in contexto.EstadoCivil on p.IDEstadoCivil equals estadoCivil.ID

                      select new
                          {
                             ID = p.ID,
                             RazaoSocial_Nome = p.RazaoSocial_Nome,
                             NomeFantasia = p.NomeFantasia,
                             CNPJ_CPF = p.CNPJ_CPF,
                             IE_RG = p.IE_RG,
                             DataNascimento = p.DataNascimento,
                             Sexo = p.Sexo,
                             IDPais = p.IDPais,
                             NomePais = pais.Nome,
                             IDProfissao = p.IDProfissao,
                             NomeProfissao = profissao.Nome,
                             IDCargo = p.IDCargo,
                             NomeCargo = cargos.Nome,
                             IDNacionalidade = p.IDNacionalidade,
                             NomeNacionalidade = nacionalidade.Nome,
                             IDEstadoCivil = p.IDEstadoCivil,
                             NomeEstadoCivil = estadoCivil.Nome,
                             Telefones = contexto.Telefone.Where(t => t.IDPFPJ == p.ID).ToList(),
                          }).AsEnumerable().Select(x => new PFPJ
                          {
                             ID = x.ID,
                             RazaoSocial_Nome = x.RazaoSocial_Nome,
                             NomeFantasia = x.NomeFantasia,
                             CNPJ_CPF = x.CNPJ_CPF,
                             IE_RG = x.IE_RG,
                             DataNascimento = x.DataNascimento,
                             Sexo = x.Sexo,
                             IDPais = x.IDPais,
                             NomePais = x.NomePais,
                             IDProfissao = x.IDProfissao,
                             NomeProfissao = x.NomeProfissao,
                             IDCargo = x.IDCargo,
                             NomeCargo = x.NomeCargo,
                             IDNacionalidade = x.IDNacionalidade,
                             NomeNacionalidade = x.NomeNacionalidade,
                             IDEstadoCivil = x.IDEstadoCivil,
                             NomeEstadoCivil = x.NomeEstadoCivil,
                             Telefones = x.Telefones
                          }).ToList();
```

Alguns **joins** já estão corretos. O que preciso agora é preencher os tipos de Telefone a cada telefone da List, nesta mesma consulta, como posso fazer?

Comment: O tipo esta na tabela Telefone?

Comment: Marconcilio o 'TipoTelefone' é outro objeto. Está no objeto Telefone. Relaciono assim:Telefone.IDTipoTelefone = TipoTelefone.ID

Comment: Preciso buscar o 'TipoTelefone' para cada objeto da List. Observação: A modelagem não é culpa minha kkkk

Answer (score 2):

Eu faria método de extensão para isso.

```
public partial class VwClienteTelefone
    {
        public PFPJ PFPJ_ { get; set; }
        public pais pais_ { get; set; }
        public profissao profissao_ { get; set; }
        public nacionalidade nacionalidade_ { get; set; }
        public estadoCivil estadoCivil_ { get; set; }
    }

    public static class ClientesExt
    {
        public static IQueryable<VwClienteTelefone> VwCamposFormulario(
            this IQueryable<PFPJ> qrIn, Context ctx)
        {
            return qrIn
                .Select(pfpj =>
                    new
                    {
                        PFPJ_ = pfpj,
                        pais_ = ctx.pais.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ID == pfpj.IDPais),
                        profissao_ = ctx.profissao.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ID == pfpj.IDProfissao),
                        cargos_ = ctx.cargos.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ID == pfpj.IDCargo),
                        nacionalidade_ = ctx.nacionalidade.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ID == pfpj.IDNacionalidade),
                        estadoCivil_ = ctx.nacionalidade.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ID == pfpj.IDEstadoCivil),
                    })
                    .Select(p => new 
                    {
                        ID = p.ID,
                        RazaoSocial_Nome = p.RazaoSocial_Nome,
                        NomeFantasia = p.NomeFantasia,
                        CNPJ_CPF = p.CNPJ_CPF,
                        IE_RG = p.IE_RG,
                        DataNascimento = p.DataNascimento,
                        Sexo = p.Sexo,
                        IDPais = p.IDPais,
                        NomePais = pais.Nome,
                        IDProfissao = p.IDProfissao,
                        NomeProfissao = profissao.Nome,
                        IDCargo = p.IDCargo,
                        NomeCargo = cargos.Nome,
                        IDNacionalidade = p.IDNacionalidade,
                        NomeNacionalidade = nacionalidade.Nome,
                        IDEstadoCivil = p.IDEstadoCivil,
                        NomeEstadoCivil = estadoCivil.Nome,
                        Telefones = contexto.Telefone.Where(t => t.IDPFPJ == p.ID).ToList(),
                    })
                    .Select(x => new VwClienteTelefone
                    {
                        ID = x.ID,
                        RazaoSocial_Nome = x.RazaoSocial_Nome,
                        NomeFantasia = x.NomeFantasia,
                        CNPJ_CPF = x.CNPJ_CPF,
                        IE_RG = x.IE_RG,
                        DataNascimento = x.DataNascimento,
                        Sexo = x.Sexo,
                        IDPais = x.IDPais,
                        NomePais = x.NomePais,
                        IDProfissao = x.IDProfissao,
                        NomeProfissao = x.NomeProfissao,
                        IDCargo = x.IDCargo,
                        NomeCargo = x.NomeCargo,
                        IDNacionalidade = x.IDNacionalidade,
                        NomeNacionalidade = x.NomeNacionalidade,
                        IDEstadoCivil = x.IDEstadoCivil,
                        NomeEstadoCivil = x.NomeEstadoCivil,
                        Telefones = x.Telefones
                    });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Marconcilio o 'TipoTelefone' é outro objeto. Está no objeto Telefone. Relaciono assim:Telefone.IDTipoTelefone = TipoTelefone.ID

Comment: Preciso buscar o 'TipoTelefone' para cada objeto da List. Observação: A modelagem não é culpa minha kkkk

Comment: você pode buscar seus dados da mesma forma que fez para o  `Telefones = contexto.Telefone.Where(t => t.IDPFPJ == p.ID).ToList(),`  no seu ultimo select se for 1 p/ 1 use o firstordefault no lugar do where.

Comment: TipoTelefone = contexto.TipoTelefone.Where(t => t.ID == x.IDTipoTelefone).ToList(),

Comment: Entendi. o relacionamento eh 1/1. Só que quero preencher o objeto 'TipoTelefone', dentro do objeto 'Telefone'. Para cada Telefone. Como ficaria no select do linq?